# How do you use conditionals within iterations using Jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to target 1 element within an iteration

http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/

```
each category in categories
    .menu_category
        p= category.category_name
```

Above is Jade, and it iterates through an an object named **categories**. Im new to this but I assume this means looping through the object. I was using ejs prior to this and to get the same results you would use their for loop

```
 for(i=0;i<object.length;i++)
```

I believe this is the same thing. Right?

I'm trying to add a class to a div for a particular div with the right **category_name** from the **categories** object.

So I'm thinking about using something like this:

```
 if(category.category_name === 'dog')
     // add another class to .menu_category, only to the div that holds 'dog'
```

Jade says in order to us conditionals, its got to look like this:

```
if user.description
    h2 Description
    p.description= user.description
else 
    h2 Description
    p.description.
```

http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/

**How do I add another class to the div that contains the data Im matching in a conditional?**

The iteration works fine, but trying to figure out how the conditional fits within the iteration is driving me nuts. Especially with all the indenting problems I have faced. I have tried too many ways to show you here. I cant quite grasp this; if you could please help connect the dots for me.

BTW the reason why I went to jade is because I couldn't access app.locals. If you have any input on that that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for. This creates a div with two classes for one specific category and with one class for others

```
each category in categories    
    if(category.category_name === 'dog')
        .menu_category.dog_category
    else
        .menu_category
            << rest of your contents here>>
```